# How to set Kendo Grid total when datasource.transport.read is set to function?

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

`Kendo version: ^2019.3.1023`

Assume I have a datasource like the one below, where the read prop is set to a function, and that the returned data is used in a [Kendo Grid](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-vue-ui/components/grid/).

The `success` callback of the XHR function/method is passed an object that contains a "page" (array of objects that are part of a paginated query result), and the total result count for the query (count of records on all "pages").

```
<script>
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
  transport: {
    read: function(options) {
      // make JSONP request to https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/products
      $.ajax({
        url: "https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/products",
        dataType: "jsonp", // "jsonp" is required for cross-domain requests; use "json" for same-domain requests
        success: function(result) {
          // notify the data source that the request succeeded
          options.success(result);
        },
        error: function(result) {
          // notify the data source that the request failed
          options.error(result);
        }
      });
    }
  }
});
dataSource.fetch(function() {
  console.log(dataSource.view().length); // displays "77"
});
</script>
```

**How can I set the grid total?**

I tried setting it in the [schema](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource/configuration/schema#schematotal), using a TypeScript getter as below, but this doesn't work.

```
{ schema: { total: this.paginatedRecordsCount }}
```

I also tried `:total="total"` in the `<kendo-datasource>`, and the `<kendo-grid>`, where total is again TypeScript getter, similarly to [this example](https://stackblitz.com/run/?file=src/main.vue), but that has no effect (even when I hardcode values).

I found this type defintion, but it's not helpful:

```
interface DataSourceTransportOptions {
    success: (data?: any) => void;
    error: (error?: any) => void;
    data: any;
}
```

This is the body of `options.success` at runtime:

```
function(data) {
    that._ranges = [];
    that.success(data, params);

    deferred.resolve();
}
```

Comment: just out of curiosity, why did you use `read` as a function?

Comment: @dev_in_progress, I needed to add some additional custom data to the "standard" data Kendo sends to the READ endpoint (it normally sends skip, take, page, etc).

Comment: in that case, you can user parameterMap, for example: https://pastebin.pl/view/233f56cf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting `total` in `schema` didn't work when `paginatedTransactionsCount` was a TypeScript getter.

```
total: this.paginatedRecordsCount
```

As it turns out, you can use a closure to access a wrapper object (containing `count`) from the success callback of the method handling XHR (`Axios.post` in my case) so that the callback can update the `count` prop in a way that is "visible" to the grid via the `schema.total` property below.

```
total: () => this.paginatedRecordsCountWrapper.count
```